# Regular Expression for APO and FPO Causing issue When city is APOAPKO, since the city name stars with APO

Tags: regex, demandware

I have to restrict APO FPO address for the City. I have done it by using this regular expression

```
var regExp : RegExp = new RegExp('^[af][ .]?p[ .]?o|[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]','i');
```

This works when there is only `APO`, `FPO`, `A.p.o`, `F.P.O` etc. pattern, but it still matches when city is `APOPKO` which should not happen.

i tried with giving `\b` after `[af][ .]?p[ .]?o` but din't work for me. Can any one please help on this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input string? Try [`^\b([af][ .]?p[ .]?o|[Pp]*(OST|ost)*)\b\.*\s*[Oo0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[Bb][Oo0][Xx]`](https://regex101.com/r/xS1lC3/1)

Comment: "APOPKO" this is the sample input string, the regular expression should match only for "APO" now it matches the above sample string since it starts from APO.

Comment: The problem is that your alternation group seems incorrect, you match either `^[af][ .]?p[ .]?o` or `[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]`. Note that `|` inside the character classes are treated as literal symbols that is why I suggest removing them in my answer.

Comment: Please see my answer - doesn't it work as you need? Try experimenting with the regex demo: paste your sample strings and see if they match.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^([af][ .]?p[ .]?o|[Pp]*(OST|ost)*)\b\.*\s*[Oo0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[Bb][Oo0][Xx]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xS1lC3/2)

I cleaned up your pattern a bit, but the POI is `^([af][ .]?p[ .]?o|[Pp]*(OST|ost)*)\b`:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - a group: matches either...

  - `[af][ .]?p[ .]?o` - `apo`-like strings: `[af]` matches either `a` or `f`, then `[ .]?` matches an optional (1 or 0) space or dot, then `p` matches `p`, then again the `[ .]?` subpattern, and `o` matches `o`.
  - `|` - or
  - `[Pp]*(OST|ost)*)` - matches `p` or `P` 0+ times (maybe you meant `?` - 1 or 0 times), then either `OST` or `ost`, again 0+ times.
- `\b` - trailing word boundary